# Warning message during build --> warning: "bool" redefined

Tags: c, gcc-warning, mosquitto

I am rewriting a Python (containing Mosquitto MQTT) script to C using Code::Blocks. As a test I used the following code available on the Mosquitto repository:

https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto/src/4deedcb49ff50be94166701f21e5c79ff7667d5b/test/lib/c/02-subscribe-qos0.c?at=default

However, this causes the following warning:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\devel\mosquitto.h|56|warning: "bool" redefined|
c:\mingw32-xy\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.5.2\include\stdbool.h|33|note: this is the location of the previous definition|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `on_connect':|
```

I've been digging into the subject, and I think it can be solved using include guards. I've did a few tests, but apparently I don't know how to apply them correctly.

Since I am not a experienced C programmer, I decided to call for some help.

EDIT: I've added the link to the [mosquitto.h code](https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto/src/4deedcb49ff50be94166701f21e5c79ff7667d5b/lib/mosquitto.h?at=default).

This is the part where it might go wrong:

```
#ifndef _MOSQUITTO_H_
#define _MOSQUITTO_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(WITH_BROKER)
#   ifdef libmosquitto_EXPORTS
#       define libmosq_EXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define libmosq_EXPORT  __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define libmosq_EXPORT
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#   ifndef __cplusplus
#       define bool char
#       define true 1
#       define false 0
#   endif
#else
#   ifndef __cplusplus
#       include <stdbool.h>
#   endif
#endif
```

Is there a quick fix to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Include guards is not the problem, exactly.

The problem is that [`mosquitto.h`](https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto/src/4deedcb49ff50be94166701f21e5c79ff7667d5b/lib/mosquitto.h?at=default) contains a re-definition of the macro `bool`, which is already defined by `<stdbool.h>`.

This only seems to trigger on Win32. It might be the result of somebody assuming "if we're building on Win32, then we're not using a C99-compliant compiler, thus we must substitute our own `stdbool.h`-compatible declarations".

That's an incorrect assumption of course; you can build with non-Microsoft compilers in Win32 just fine. That's probably what you're doing; Code::Blocks can use GCC.

I'd say the logic in `mosquitto.h` needs fixing.